# If I am transiting a class delta airspace on a VFR flight and am coming up to a class bravo boundary without a bravo clearance, what will happen?

Tags: air-traffic-control

Kind of an edge case, but will the class delta controller ask me to "say intentions"? Or maybe let a bravo controller know I could be entering without permission?

Answer (score 4):

Because you're in Delta space, you are necessarily talking with a Delta controller.
They will likely do one of two things:

***Either***:

- give you a vector to keep you clear of Bravo:
  *N45WTF:  Turn left 40 degrees*
- coordinate with the Bravo controller, and the Delta controller may give you clearance:
  *N45WTF:  Climb and maintain 3,500.  Squawk 3462, Cleared into the Bravo, contact Center on 118.9*

Comment: Thanks. If the delta controller doesn't coordinate your bravo clearance, how does an aircraft legally remain in the delta when switching frequencies to contact the bravo for clearance (to be in class delta airspace, pilots need to establish AND maintain two-way communications)? Maneuvering the aircraft to leave the class delta airspace to contact the bravo controller sounds like too much of a hassle to me, but then again rules are rules.

Comment: *"Tower:  N45WTF requests frequency change to Center"*  (tower will respond with:  *"Frequency Change Approved, switch to 118.9"*).  If you request it, and they approve it, you're allowed to switch frequency.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely, you would be talking to Approach before entering the Delta if they are that close. You will talk to Delta, they will arrange the clearance into Bravo before handing you off, or hand you off to Approach for Bravo and tell you to remain clear.